# Restore and back up of vm in azure

Tags: c#, azure, cloud, hyper-v

I want to take the backup and restore vm in azure.I could able to get the backup of vm as xml file, store it in the local machine and restore it back to windows azure successfully. But now my requirement is to take the backup of a vm from windows azure and restore it to hyper v. and vice varsa. is it possible? and how it can be done and i want to perform this operation programmatically.

waiting for the reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think when you say you "could able to get the backup of VM as XML", you are actually saving the Windows Azure VM configuration and then use the same configuration to create another Windows Azure Virtual Machine.

If you want to download a OS Disk or Data Disk VHD related with a Windows Azure Virtual Machine, you can just simply download the VHD from Windows Azure Storage. If you want to do it programmatically, you can use Powershell in your program or just use Windows Azure Storage API to download the VHD as page Blob or just use REST API to download the blob.

I have explained the steps in the following Windows Azure Virtual Machine Forum question:

[Download a Virtual Machine VHD](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/WAVirtualMachinesforWindows/thread/5e851d21-8829-4fec-aa4a-a45258ec5da2)

Technically I could see a case where you can download a VM (as OS Disk VHD) for backup purpose (you can actually backup it up in Azure Storage for quickly access) however downloading from DC and then uploading does not make sense as you can log into the VM and install whatever you want or configure the way you want. Bringing down the VHD and then uploading again could be a significant design issue. I am interested to listen about your scenario.

Comment: thank u.:) i tried with the powershell command and able to get the vhd file. and the same vhd file van be used in hyper v.